# Link on the side of the review queue should be more intuitive

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, user-interface, user-experience

The *"link"* on side of the review queue being called *"link"* is a little unintuitive and vague. Wouldn't it be better to use the wording *"View the original question"* or something? Simply the word *"link"*, hardly describes it's function:

[image]

---

I actually thought this was a bug until someone pointed out my error!

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I'd support a [meta-tag:feature-request] for changing that text to "view the post" or "link to the post".

Comment: Changed to a feature request

Comment: The other link is also unclear. It should be phrased as an action, "Flag this post as low quality" or similar.

Comment: What's the point of the "link" link anyway? The title already links to the post.

Comment: I agree @NisseEngström. The whole thing is confusing

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pretty clear from the context what's the meaning of "link", since you're reviewing a post, having "question is very low quality" and "link" links is enough to know where that link links to.

Comment: I respectively disagree. :)

Comment: That's only my opinion :)

Comment: @Deduplicator typo #toolatetoedit :(